# Start up Fabric Composer REST API server

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to use the composer-rest-server package after completing the Fabric Composer quick start, but I failed.

Please give me a hint.

The composer-rest-server package was successfully installed.

`npm install -g composer-rest-server`

Composer-rest-server started.

`composer-rest-server`

I was asked to enter simple information about the business network.
After that, I failed to load the connector module 'composer-connector-hlf'.

```
? Enter your Fabric Connection Profile Name: defaultProfile　
? Enter your Business Network Identifier : digitalproperty-network
? Enter your Fabric username : WebAppAdmin
? Enter your secret: DJY27pEnl16d
? Specify if you want namespaces in the generated REST API: always use namespace
s
? Specify if you want the generated REST API to be secured: Yes

To restart the REST server using the same options, issue the following command:
   composer-rest-server -p defaultProfile -n digitalproperty-network -i WebAppAdmin -s DJY27pEnl16d -N always -S true

Discovering types from business network definition ...
Connection fails: Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlf" for connection profile "defaultProfile"
It will be retried for the next request.
Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlf" for connection profile "defaultProfile"
    at connectionProfileStore.load.then.e (/home/user1/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/connectionprofilemanager.js:148:27)
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: if you cannot load the connector, it usually means that the npm install had some problems resolving the dependent module 'composer-connector-hlf' for the composer-rest-server. Alternatively try uninstalling and re-installing the rest server in case there were problems with the npm repository

Comment: This is almost always an install problem. Try npm uninstall -g composer-cli followed by npm install -g composer-cli and then do the same for the composer-rest-server package. Watch the output closely for install errors. If you have install errors it is usually because you are using an unsupported version of node or npm.

Comment: I was able to solve it with hints from your answers and comments.
Due to version discrepancies of some modules and access permissions, it was caused.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Does your grpc module has **grpc_node.node** files?
It's in the composer-cli module.

In my environment 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node

if you use sudo, you may need to add **--unsafe-perm** option.
Like: sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm composer-cli

Comment: I don't recommend installing npm modules using sudo.

Answer (score 2):

Your .composer-connection-profiles is not set to defaultprofile.

Check your root folder and there .composer-connection-profiles folder must be present.

Inside that folder the composer profiles will be there (if your defaultprofile is made, then there will be a folder named defaultprofile), check the connection.json inside the defaultprofile folder.

If there is any other folder with different name, use that as your profile. Or you can specifically define the folder defaultprofile and write connection.json with connection details.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of npm are you using? I faced similar issue on ubuntu 16.4. When I retinstall evberything with lower version of npm it worked perfectly.

npm version when things worked:

```
npm --version
3.10.10
```

when I was getting problem as you have mentioned it was 5.x

Comment: Composer does not currently support npm v5. Supported versions are here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html